# Creation of DLL, unable to resolve new, delete and new[]

Tags: visual-c++, linker, new-operator

Creating a DLL using "vault" library. It compiles fine, but it has a problem linking since VS2013 is not able to resolve new, new[] and delete operators. Not using precompiled headers. If I use precompiled headers, I need to add #include"stdafx.h" in all the source files, and even if I do that it still cannot link. I tried adding new.cpp and new.h in the project but that too is of no use. Please let me know how I can solve this issue. These are the errors,

`Error   53  error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals

    C:\Users\dwane\Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\newest - 2\Debug\projDLL.dll    projDLL
    Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int,char const *,int)" (??2@YAPAXIPBDH@Z)

    C:\Users\dwane\Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\newest - 2\vthreadsunit.obj projDLL
    Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int,char const *,int)" (??2@YAPAXIPBDH@Z)

    C:\Users\dwane\Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\newest - 2\vunit.obj    projDLL
    Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int,char const *,int)" (??2@YAPAXIPBDH@Z)

    C:\Users\dwane\Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\newest - 2\vbentounit.obj   projDLL
.
.
.`

Turning on verbose says this:

    `Starting pass 1
    1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT
    1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
    1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:msvcprtd
    1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib
    1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib
    1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib
    1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:libboost_chrono-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib
    1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:ws2_32.lib
    1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:mswsock.lib
    1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib
    1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib`

Before listing out the errors(above) it says these lines:

```
1>  Unused libraries:
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\User32.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib
1>    C:\Users\anantra\Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\newest\boost\x86\libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib
1>    C:\Users\anantra\Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\newest\boost\x86\libboost_chrono-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\mswsock.lib


1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\uuid.lib
```

Comment: You need to edit & provide better post to get help, otherwise this'll get closed. As it is you haven't provided enough sufficient relevant info.

Comment: @ReturnVoid please let me know what other information is needed so that I can provide you with it. thanks!

Comment: Perhaps some code & settings you're actually using, & remove all these errors from your OP, they don't really help much except tell you exactly what the problem is which I'm sure you could summarize better.

Comment: Did you by any chance 'ignore default libraries'? (check properties/linker/input)

Comment: @OfekShilon Thanks! I checked that, it didnt have a value, so I explicitely mentioned "NO" but I still get the same errors.

Comment: @ReturnVoid I am not able to upload more than 1 image that I took of my settings(linker/cpp settings), please let me know what you would be interested in and I can let you know. Thanks!

Comment: set the linker switch /VERBOSE, and compare the outputs to a VERBOSE output from a VS2013 that links successfully.  Inspect in particular the NODEFAULTLIB statements

Comment: @OfekShilon thanks for the input, I made the linker output /VERBOSE and I have attached the significant parts in the question(edited it). It says User32.lib, is that what it uses to find new and delete?

Comment: @OfekShilon Also I have specified the RunTime Library as Multi-threaded DLL(/MD) since I want to create a DLL. Is that right?

Comment: @user7795930 the libraries that implement new/delete are msvc libraries, not windows ones. Stuff like ucrtbase, vcruntime, etc.  Do you see none of them?  If you create a toy console project, are you able to build it? Can you compare the VERBOSE outputs of a toy project and your current one?

Comment: @OfekShilon: Yes, I am able to build small projects, even with new and delete used. Not sure why this one wont build, I am thinking I have someother configuration wrong. I will compare a the /VERBOSE output of a sample console application using new and delete with this and let you know what I find. Thanks!